# Private star network topology on Sub-1GHz

Tags: transmitter, lora

I have a project which there is a need to be implemented many sensor nodes in a star network topology. One collector-gateway and multiple transmitters.

The farthest sensor node from the "collector-gateway" would be about 2km.

All sensor nodes would work with battery and would take measurement from their environment such as soil moisture, air temperature, air humidity, sound level and some other "internal data" about its status like internal battery level etc...

The number of transmitters may be more than 20, or in some cases it may exceed the number of 100. It depends on the needs. So I need something that I can customize easily.

First, I was thinking about using TI's CC1310 but I have second thoughts to go with LoRa.

What physical interface or technology would be fit better in my case?

Either way I intend to use my own GSM based gateway and my own server with my own protocol based on HTTP connection.

Comment: TI is one of the few not going with LoRa. This is their pitch (biased of course) http://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/TI-Long-range-RF-communication.pdf. The LoRa PHY is really good (read on LoRa vs. LoRa WAN) and is recommended.

Comment: @MrBit: What is your actual question? There is no question mark in your post.

Comment: You're right, the question is hidden, sorry for that. My question is which technology must I stick with. So far, I am between CC1310 and LoRa

Comment: I added the question

Answer (score 0):

LoRa as a physical layer will work fine in your case. You can use just the radio PHY (for example RFM95) and you don't have to implement the full LoRaWAN stack.

Some other problems to think about:

- Unidirectional or bidirectional transmission (should the sensor transmit again if the base station does not confirm)?
- Collision avoidance
- Network capacity
- Retransmissions

Comment: Of course I wouldn't like to implement any stack that it would be useless. But I think that I lean more towards LoRa.

Comment: In doing research for something vaguely similar, came across https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8048465/ which might be of interest to you. I haven't thoroughly read it, not sure if I'll understand it 100% even when I do, but I think it might be useful.